# UITableView creeps underneath button

Tags: ios, ipad, uitableview

I created a UITableView with a button underneath. When I run the app on iPad in portrait, the UITableView creeps under the button, like so:

[image]

I am clueless as to why this happens. It only happens on iPad in portrait, so I don't think it's a Xib problem.

I would very much appreciate any help with this problem.

Comment: How are you creating the UI? Are you using Interface Builder or are you creating it programatically?

Comment: I am using Interface Builder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your tableView's content is not clipping to the bounds of the frame. Try setting clipsToBounds to YES for the tableView.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to set the UITableView's frame manually when the iPad in portrait as the UITableView may be autoresizing with traits such as sticking to the button of the screen like below. You can play around with the resize options of both the UITableView and UIButton to get this right.

[image: Xcode resize]

To set the frame manually, set a `CGRect` to the `frame` of the element.

```
tableView.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x,self.view.frame.origin.y,self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height - uploadButton.frame.size.height);
```

In this example, uploadButton is the UIButton at the bottom and you are resizing tableView to fill the screen except to the uploadButton at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to add an autolayout contraint to keep the bottom edge of the table view and the top edge of the button a certain distance apart.

Comment: I cannot use autolayout because I want to support old versions of iOS.